# Match row selected to pass data

Tags: json, swift, chat, messaging

I've taken a look at all these Swift, and asp.net, and javascript questions.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025358/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-and-strin)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871583/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-anyobject-and-str)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540039/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-double)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052609/mvc-pass-model-object-from-controller-to-view)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857379/pass-model-from-view-to-controller)

**Goal:**
When I select a messages from the list of chat messages in the `MessageListController` I want the opened session in the next `ChatDetailController` to be the conversation that was selected.

I'm doing the same thing in this iOS image for my WatchKit app. The message with Sophia is selected and the chat with Sophia opens. 
[![enter image description here][6]][6]

I want to pass the json "message_id" i.e. the `chatMessageId` property. I'm already passing the `chatMessageId` from the `MessageModel`to the `ChatDetailController` as you can see in code.

Is it the `chatMessageId` of the `ChatModel`I need to pass? Or am I already passing the data that I need?

> Passed context: Optional(HTWatch_Extension.MessageModel(partner: "9859", nickname: "Marco", message: "Have you seen is dog?", city: "Madrid", countryBadgeImageURL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg, messageListImageURL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg, chatMessageId: "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ", status: "offline"))

**Attempt:**
Do I need to take the do-catch block where I parse the `ChatModel` out of the `ChatDetailController`'s `awakeWithContext` method and put it in the `didSelectRowAt` method of the `MessageListController`?

MessageListController

```
// ...code...

var messageObject = [MessageModel]()
var chatObject = [ChatModel]()

// ...code...

override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {

    var messageContext = messageObject[rowIndex]
    var chatContext = chatObject[rowIndex]

    do {
        guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chats", withExtension: "json") else {
            print("File could not be located")
            return
        }
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        let msg = try decoder.decode([ChatModel].self, from: data)
        self.chatObject = msg

    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

    messageContext.chatMessageId = (chatObject as AnyObject).filter { (dictionaryTemp:[String:String]) -> Bool in
        return dictionaryTemp["message_id"] == chatContext.chatMessageId
    } 

    // WatchKit's model presentation method.
    presentController(withName: "ChatDetailController", context: messageContext)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, your `Chat.json`, will have chat's for all message id's. Select one of the message id row and load the respective chat history.

In that case you can parse based on message by using `filter`. Let's say you have it in a dictionary like this.

Example:

```
let responseString = "{\"name\":\"Tom\"}"

if let responseData = responseString.data(using: .utf8){
    do {

    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:responseData , options: .allowFragments)
    print("Response Object=\(object)")
    } catch{
        print("parsing Error=\(error)")
    }
}
```

You can use a similar code to create your Object. The final object should be something like `chatDictionary`

```
let chatDictionary = [
[
    "fromId": "zz1234skjksmsjdfwe2zz",
    "toId": "qq43922sdkfjsfmmxdfqq",
    "messageText": "Have you seen is dog?",
    "imageUrl": "https://i.imgur.com/PJcyle7.jpg",
    "message_id": "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ",
    "read": "true"
    ],
[
    "fromId": "zz1234skjksmsjdfwe2zz",
    "toId": "qq43922sdkfjsfmmxdfqq",
    "messageText": "Yes I have. It's cute.",
    "imageUrl": "https://i.imgur.com/PJcyle7.jpg",
    "message_id": "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ",
    "read": "true"
    ],
[
    "fromId": "zz1234skjksmsjdfwe2zz",
    "toId": "qq43922sdkfjsfmmxdfqq",
    "messageText": "I want to get a pet too.",
    "imageUrl": "https://i.imgur.com/PJcyle7.jpg",
    "message_id": "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ1",
    "read": "true"
    ]
]
```

Your did Select Row At index

```
    override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {

            let message = messageObjects[rowIndex]
            // Create a chat object Dictionary, parse it before you pass it to the detail View Controller , if you have the chat.json.
// I have used 'Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ', but here you can your message id property to make it dynamic
            message.chatObjects= chatDictionary.filter { (dictionaryTemp:[String : String]) -> Bool in
            return dictionaryTemp["message_id"] == "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ"
        }
            presentController(withName: "ChatDetailController", context: message)
        }
```

Comment: I am considering the chat.json and message.json, in the way you have mentioned. I am using a JSONSerialization, to get the Object from String.

Comment: Your datastructure is correct, I don't see any issues with it, but I am presuming you have two network calls, one to get the Message.json and the other one for Chat.json. with my example I have explained using Dictionary but you can apply the same filter on Chat Array Object.

Comment: Today I was looking over my account and noticed I hadn't marked your answer as correct. Sorry for the late vote.